# Haskell correct types for class and instance

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I am struggling to describe what it means for terms and literals (first order logic) to be re-written. Ie I would like a function `applySubstitution` that can be called on both terms and literals. 
I thought that the substitution could be expressed as a function. However I am getting rigid type variable errors with the following code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

module Miniexample where
import qualified Data.Maybe as M

data Term a = F a [Term a]
            | V a

data Literal a = P a [Term a]
               | E (Term a) (Term a)

class Substitutable b where
  substitute :: b -> (Term a -> Maybe (Term a)) -> b

instance Substitutable (Term a) where
  substitute x@(V _) σ    = M.fromMaybe x (σ x)
  substitute f@(F l xs) σ = M.fromMaybe f' (σ f)
    where f' = F l (map (flip substitute σ) xs)

instance Substitutable (Literal a) where
  substitute (P l xs) σ = P l (map (flip substitute σ) xs)
  substitute (E s t) σ  = E (substitute s σ) (substitute t σ)

class Substitution σ where
  asSub :: σ -> (a -> Maybe a)

applySubstitution σ t = substitute t (asSub σ)

(<|) t σ = applySubstitution σ t
```

This gives be the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘a’
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      substitute :: forall a1.
                    Term a -> (Term a1 -> Maybe (Term a1)) -> Term a
    at /.../Miniexample.hs:16:3-12
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
    at /.../Miniexample.hs:15:10-31
  Expected type: Term a1
    Actual type: Term a
• In the first argument of ‘σ’, namely ‘x’
  In the second argument of ‘M.fromMaybe’, namely ‘(σ x)’
  In the expression: M.fromMaybe x (σ x)
• Relevant bindings include
    σ :: Term a1 -> Maybe (Term a1)
      (bound at /.../Miniexample.hs:16:22)
    x :: Term a
      (bound at /.../Miniexample.hs:16:14)
    substitute :: Term a -> (Term a1 -> Maybe (Term a1)) -> Term a
      (bound at /.../Miniexample.hs:16:3)
```

In my head, the type variable `b` in the `Substitutable` class should be able to take on (bad terminology I'm sure) the the value of `Term a`.

Any hints would be greatly welcome.

To give a more concrete example, the following works, but one needs to be explicit about which function `applyTermSub` or `applyLitSub` to call and secondly the implementation of the substitution map leaks into the implementation of the more general procedure.

```
module Miniexample where
import qualified Data.Maybe as M
import qualified Data.List as L

data Term a = F a [Term a]
            | V a deriving (Eq)

data Literal a = P a [Term a]
               | E (Term a) (Term a) deriving (Eq)


termSubstitute :: (Term a -> Maybe (Term a)) -> Term a -> Term a
termSubstitute σ x@(V _)    = M.fromMaybe x (σ x)
termSubstitute σ f@(F l xs) = M.fromMaybe f' (σ f)
    where f' = F l (map (termSubstitute σ) xs)

litSubstitute :: (Term a -> Maybe (Term a)) -> Literal a -> Literal a
litSubstitute σ (P l xs) = P l (map (termSubstitute σ) xs)
litSubstitute σ (E s t)  = E (termSubstitute σ s) (termSubstitute σ t)

applyTermSub :: (Eq a) => Term a -> [(Term a, Term a)] -> Term a
applyTermSub t σ = termSubstitute (flip L.lookup σ) t

applyLitSub :: (Eq a) => Literal a -> [(Term a, Term a)] -> Literal a
applyLitSub l σ = litSubstitute (flip L.lookup σ) l

-- variables
x  = V "x"
y  = V "y"
-- constants
a  = F "a" []
b  = F "b" []
-- functions
fa = F "f" [a]
fx = F "f" [x]

σ = [(x,y), (fx, fa)]

test = (applyLitSub (P "p" [x, b, fx]) σ) == (P "p" [y, b, fa])
```

Ideally I would like to have an interface for substitutions (i.e one could use `Data.Map` etc) and secondly I would like a single substitute function that captures both term and literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is a complaint that `Term a`, as specified in `instance Substitutable (Term a)`, is not the same type as the `Term a` that `σ` accepts. This is because Haskell quantifies `a` over the `substitute` function, but not over the rest of the instance definition. So an implementation of `substitute` must accept a `σ` that handles `Term a1` for *some* value of `a1`, which is not guaranteed to be the specific `a` that your instance is defined on. (Yes, your instance is defined over all `a`... but from inside the scope of the instance definition, it's as if a specific `a` has been chosen.)

You can avoid this by parameterizing your `Substitutable` class by a type constructor instead of just a type, and passing the same `a` to that type constructor as is used in the `σ` type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

import qualified Data.Maybe as M
import qualified Data.List as L

data Term a = F a [Term a]
            | V a deriving (Eq)

data Literal a = P a [Term a]
               | E (Term a) (Term a) deriving (Eq)

class Substitutable f where
  substitute :: f a -> (Term a -> Maybe (Term a)) -> f a

instance Substitutable Term where
  substitute x@(V _) σ    = M.fromMaybe x (σ x)
  substitute f@(F l xs) σ = M.fromMaybe f' (σ f)
    where f' = F l (map (flip substitute σ) xs)

instance Substitutable Literal where
  substitute (P l xs) σ = P l (map (flip substitute σ) xs)
  substitute (E s t) σ  = E (substitute s σ) (substitute t σ)

(<|) t σ = substitute t $ flip L.lookup σ


-- variables
x  = V "x"
y  = V "y"
-- constants
a  = F "a" []
b  = F "b" []
-- functions
fa = F "f" [a]
fx = F "f" [x]

σ = [(x,y), (fx, fa)]


main = print $ show $ (P "p" [x, b, fx] <| σ) == P "p" [y, b, fa]
```

Comment: But now you're never going to be able to sensibly instantiate `Substitution`. I don't think this is the right direction to go.

Comment: Why not? You should be able to define any substitution that rearranges, but doesn't inspect, the `a` types in terms and literals. I'm not entirely clear how the `Substitution` class is intended to be used in this example, so maybe there are more issues with making this usable.

Comment: By parametricity, `asSub` cannot inspect its second argument at all. So `asSub` will associate each `σ` with either `const Nothing` or `Just` (or something less defined), finally resulting in `applySubstitution σ t = t` (or something less defined).

Comment: I have added a working example of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: That example cleared up a lot! See rewritten answer.